# NuxtJS: Concat bind value?

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs

So does NuxtJS have support for concatting a string literal with a dynamic variable, to bind a tag's href attribute? Their documentation seems to mention nothing about it.

Like:

```
<a :href="('https://customu.rl/' + getProfile.data.profile_data.username)"
```

The above seems to be rendering `undefined`.

Also tried this, no luck:

```
<a :href="'https://customu.rl/' + getProfile.data.profile_data.username"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second option seems to be right.
I think your property `getProfile.data.profile_data.username` returns `undefined`.

I created a simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-a-href-nzxlz) where you can see the functionality you require.

Let me know if it helps.